# How can I share the same instance of Bonsai ElasticSearch between two apps on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, elasticsearch

I have one app that runs Bonsai Elastic Search for searching for content in my main app.  Then I have a management app for mass uploading content via a second app, both on Heroku  The problem I am having is that I need Elastic Search to pick up the mass uploaded content so they can be searched on the main app, but currently it is not.  I have added my BONSAI_URL to my configuration in Heroku on the second app, and created a model, with the same name, on the second app, that establishes a connection to the main app's postgres database and added the following elastic search require and includes to the model:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Place < MainBase

  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

end
```

Anyone know how I can share Bonsai ElasticSearch between my two apps?  or what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can create a initializers/elastic_search.rb file with your bonsai_url

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
require 'elasticsearch/transport'

if Rails.env.production?
  Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['BONSAI_URL']
end
```